# GSON issue when parsing a strange JSON string

Tags: android, json, gson

i have the below json string,

```
"objects": [{
    "d430f6c0-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180": {
        "id": "d430f6c0-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180",
        "in_use": 0,
        "alterable": 1,
        "comment": ""
    },
        "123-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180": {
        "id": "123-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180",
        "in_use": 2,
        "alterable": 3,
        "comment": "dfgfg"
    }
}]
```

and cant figure out a way to parse it, all objects in the array have the id in front as shown above. 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: json response data is not a valid format

Comment: Check your json in https://jsonlint.com/ site. it is not valid.

Comment: this is the response that comes out from an external API. Is there a way to parse it, or i will have to find a way to alter the API output?

Comment: This looks like part of a bigger JSON data.

Comment: yes it is, but the issue is that it doesnt parse the particular objects because of the additional data. And as stated above  its not valid json, i am aware of that.

Comment: create a custom deserializer for objects in `objects` array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your json array is in wrong format you can check it [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)
your json data will be like this:

```
{"objects": [{
"d430f6c0-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180": {
    "id": "d430f6c0-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180",
    "in_use": 0,
    "alterable": 1,
    "comment": ""
},
    "123-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180": {
    "id": "123-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180",
    "in_use": 2,
    "alterable": 3,
    "comment": "dfgfg"
}
}]}
```

now for parsing this data you can use this method:

```
public void parseData(String jsonObjectData) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonObjectData);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("objects");

        for (int i = 0 ; i <jsonArray.length(); i ++)
        {
      String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("d430f6c0-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180").getString("id");
            Log.d("id", id);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


}
```

you have to get json object like this `String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("d430f6c0-a293-4fb9-86fe-a163618cf180").getString("id");`

it will provide single object data, you cannot fetch all because your json is not in proper format.

Comment: that would be a good idea, but the ids in front of each object are not static. if it was static i would have created a simple POJO class from it. They are dynamic.

Comment: yes i know but if the array contain only 2 or 3 item and object are static then it is possible. and POJO class idea also good we can make it and with Gson , we can parse easily.

Comment: if object is not static then i think not possible to parse this. you can do one thing, take object name inside object.

Comment: that was one of my thoughts, but how can you just get the id in the object or the id that is out of that object? how can you target it?